# How to used copied file name using "yn" command in ranger

Tags: linux, i3-window-manager, ranger

I am using ranger file manager and I came across a command to copy the filename. How do I use this yank file name in other command? I mean, read
from clipboard. I tried using Shift+Insert. I am not getting the
copied file name.

For example in ranger, I select a file and type `yn`. This will copy the file name. Now I just want to use this copied file name and create another file or rename an existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste the copied text. For example, `:touch` followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> creates a file with the name you just `yn`'ed. Or you can do `:rename` on a selected file.

If <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> isn't working, then you need to provide more information. For instance if you're using Ubuntu, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397972/use-shiftinsert-to-paste-from-clipboard-in-gnome-terminal) might be useful.